# SVG-animation on hover - first steps, how to?

Tags: svg, svg-animate, svg.js

I'd like to do an animation to an element when hovering it. [image: this is the way, the result shall somehow look like]

As I do use svg-elements for both situations (standard and hover-state) I guess I must somehow manipulate the first svg-element when hovering it by editing the svg-code inline.

I basically'd need a starting point there:
How would I "redraw" in an animated manner the hover-image and not just swap it?
Do I need a 3rd party library (which)? 
If I had multiple of these situations, how would I keep my code clean by not having 10 svg-codes inline within my html-source?

Thanks for your answer(s)!

The code for the svg-image(s) is here

```
<svg id="Ebene_1" data-name="Ebene 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1280 800">
    <defs><style>.cls-1,.cls-2{fill:none;stroke:#000;}.cls-1{stroke-miterlimit:10;stroke-width:7px;}.cls-2{stroke-linejoin:bevel;stroke-width:5px;}</style></defs>
    <title>arrows_demoZeichenfläche 1</title>
    <line class="cls-1" x1="325.5" y1="333" x2="325.5" y2="539"/>
    <polyline class="cls-2" points="242 455.67 325.75 539.42 409.42 455.75"/><path class="cls-1" d="M670.5,135.79c0,11.62-8,11.73-8,23.35s8,11.68,8,23.3-8,11.65-8,23.28,8,11.64,8,23.26-8,11.63-8,23.25,8,11.63,8,23.25-8,11.63-8,23.25,8,11.63,8,23.25-8,11.62-8,23.25,8,11.62,8,23.25-8,11.63-8,23.25,8,11.63,8,23.25-8,11.62-8,23.25,8,11.62,8,23.25-8,11.63-8,23.25,8,11.63,8,23.25v31"/>
    <polyline class="cls-2" points="587 455.67 670.75 539.42 754.42 455.75"/></svg>
```

Comment: Look at greensock ... but do you really want a huge library for a state that will not work on touch devices? How to swap on hover depends on how you use the svg on the page: inline svg, img, background image. Can do using only css or via js.

Answer (score 1):

You could use JavaScript to manipulate the value of the `points` attribute, but such changes would be sudden, so the change would look like a stop motion film.

Like this **[Codepen](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/dNrMob)**, what you could do is give a `path` element a `stroke-dasharray` that is equal to the `getTotalLength` of the `path` in order to "erase" the straight line (of the arrow) off the page, then quickly switch the value of the `d` attribute, and then "redraw" the line back onto the page?

However, I don't believe that's what you're looking for. I believe HTML5 Canvas, with my limited knowledge about it, would be the more feasible option for what you're trying to accomplish.

Actually, I guess it might be possible using a CSS3 3D transform, [like so](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/ggErKR). The problem, however, is that the line doesn't have any depth, so when you initially set `rotateX(90deg)` on the `path` in CSS the line becomes invisible instead of appearing as a straight line...